# Modal Dialog Not Auto-Resizing in Firefox

Tags: modal-dialog

I am working a custom master page. For some reason, the modal popups do not resize consistently in different browsers. The worst offender is Firefox, which renders the modal popup with no height. All you can see is the modal dialog's title. Everything works as expected when i use v4.master.

Any idea what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are two classes for styling modal dialogs that you need to know about.

- `.ms-dialog` - This when added to a class will change the styles only in a modal dialog.

For eg:

```
.ms-dialog body #s4-ribbonrow {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

- `s4-notdlg` - This class when added with other classes in your master page, will eliminate that particular class from even appearing in the modal dialog.

Try adding either of them in your custom master page and check the difference in Firefox too.

Good Luck.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance. However, adding a width/height to `.ms-dialog` does not seem to have any affect in any browser. Maybe there is a child element/class of `.ms-dialog` i should be targeting, but i cannot find it.

Comment: i think you should be checking the details in Firebug from Firefox, which can tell you which class `.ms-dialog` should be applied for.

Comment: I had already been debugging with Firebug for hours. All changes inside the modal dialog's iframe (ie the ones inside `.ms-dialog`) have no effect on the dimensions of the modal dialog. All changes outside the iframe (ie `.ms-dlgContent`, `.ms-dlgFrameContainer` ...) are overwritten when SharePoint's javascript auto-resizes the modal dialog on launch.